# Interface variables - sliders affecting sliders

Tags: interface, netlogo

Let's say I have two sliders on my interface. Slider one goes from 0-500 and slider two goes from 0-100.

Is there anyway of setting it so that the value of slider one influences the possible values for slider two. So if I set slider one to 500, slider two can only be values from 0-30, for example.

Alternatively it would not necessarily have to be a slider affecting another slier, it could be a button. So if I have buttons A and B, if I select A the slider can be 0-10 but if I select B only 20-50.

Bit of a strange query I admit, I've just been tasked with making an interactive "model" for kids to try out different systems.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  Example: make 3 sliders: `test0`, `test1`, `test2`.  Let the min and max values of `test0` be `test1` and `test2`.  Let the min and max values of `test1` be `0` and `5`, and set a value of `1`.  Let the min and max values of `test2` be `95` and `100`, and set a value of `99`.  Your `test0` slider will now work as hoped.

BUT what happens if you make the min and max values of `test0` to `test2` and `test1`?  OK, you get odd behavior, which is likely to look broken to your "kids".  So ... this arrangement is not a good one.  If you describe your goals in more details, maybe we can find a better solution.

Comment: This feature of NetLogo (allowing reporters as slider bounds) is rather poorly implemented; I don't recommend using it.

Comment: Hi Alan, 

Thanks for this - it works and it should be good enough. I'll show it to the boss and he will give the yes or no.

To be honest I only have a certain idea what I'm meant to be doing, I've been given a brief by my boss and am currently investigating what is possible.

The idea is that there will be three feeds (as buttons). You choose feed and can then select various other variables (spend on welfare, fertiliser use etc). But what you choose or spend on 1 variable means you can't spend as much on another. If you get the idea. Sorry I can't give a better description at this time.

Comment: For the problem as you describe it in your comment, you probably should create only two sliders, and determine the 3rd value determined as a residual (after an error check).  You can show the value of the third in a monitor rather than in a slider.  Fwiw.