# NetLogo: create patchy landscape - sweep 3 parameters?

Tags: netlogo

I have a very specific problem:
I would like to produce a gridded landscape, defined by 3 sliders:

- radius - define size of clumped patches (yellow) by radius value
- Grid - distance between clumps
- %_weak - how many patches I want to have yellow from my landscape??

I would like to use all of this 3 parameters interactively. However, at certain combination of distance vs Grid vs. %_weak I don't obtain the same `count patches with [pcolor  = yellow]` as it was defined by slider `%_weak`.

[image]

Please, how can I possibly keep all of my sliders without enlarging my world size? I prefer not to extend the dimension of my world more then 601x601.

My model is available here: http://ulozto.cz/xdSN2ikr/turtles-in-grid3-nlogo, or code here:

```
globals [
      cells-in-cluster    ; # of patches in 1 cluster
      clusters_number              ; # total number of clusters over world 
]
to setup   
   clear-all   
   setup-patches 
end

to setup-patches   
  ask patches [set pcolor black]
; calculate # of patches in 1 cluster, to calculate how many clusters do I need   


  ask patch 0 0   [
    set pcolor green
    ask patches in-radius radius
      [set pcolor green]
    set cells-in-cluster count patches with [ pcolor = green ]
    ; calculate # of clusters

    set clusters_number round ((world-width * world-height / 100 * %_weak) / cells-in-cluster)
    ask patches with [pcolor = green] [set pcolor black]   ] 
  ; create grid over world - depends on radius value and clusters-number value   


  crt 1   [ 
    let $n 0  ; actual number ofturtles on this patch
    let $s 0  ; current number of turtles on a side of square pattern - 1
    set heading 0
    ask patch-here [set pcolor red]
    repeat clusters_number    ; number of needed turtles
      [ 
         hatch 1 jump Grid   ; make one turtle and move
        set $n $n + 1 ; increment count of curent side
        ask patch-here [set pcolor red]
        if $n > $s    ; if side finished...
          [ 
            right 90 set $n 0   ; turn and reset count

            ask patch-here [set pcolor red]        
            if heading mod 180 = 0 [ 
              set $s $s + 1  ; if headed up or down, increment side count
            ]
          ]

      ]    
    die   
  ]   

  ask turtles [die]     ; ask all turtles to die
; create halo effect around "clusters-numbers" patches with radius value   
      ask patches with [pcolor = red]    
        [ 
          ask patches
          in-radius radius 
          [ set pcolor yellow 
          ]   
        ] 
    end
```

Comment: It seems your question is a version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345438/interface-variables-sliders-affecting-sliders/30348745#30348745

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am confused about the logic of your program, %weak  is limited by Grid and Radius and in a closed environment you should adjust the radius or distance of green patches to get your desired ratio:

- cells-in-cluster can be calculated by asking one of green patches to count patches in its radius '**radius**',
- clusters_number can be calculated by counting green patches which depends on selected **grid** size.
- Total number of Yellow patches are `cells-in-cluster * clusters_number`
- Your code wont handle a %weak value more than `(Total number of Yellow Patches / Count patches) * 100`

This is simplified version of your code:

```
globals [
  cells-in-cluster    ; # of patches in 1 cluster
  NumberOfClusters     ; # total number of clusters over world 
  RateOfYellowPatches

]
to setup   
  clear-all   
  SetTheBasicGrid
  setPatchedInRadius  

end

to SetTheBasicGrid

  ask patches with [pycor mod Grid = 0 and pxcor mod Grid = 0]
  [
    set pcolor green
  ]
  set NumberOfClusters  count patches with [ pcolor = green ]
  ask one-of patches with [pcolor = green] 
  [
    set cells-in-cluster count patches in-radius radius 
  ]

  set RateOfYellowPatches   ((count patches *  %_weak) / cells-in-cluster )
end

to setPatchedInRadius
  ask patches with [pcolor = green] 
    [ if  count patches with [pcolor  = yellow ] <= RateOfYellowPatches   
      [
          ask patches in-radius radius 
          [ 
            set pcolor yellow 
          ]
      ]
    ]
end
```

Comment: I don't see a need for the `foreach sort`... can't you just do `ask` there?

Comment: I wanted  to start from a corner and add yellow patches , ask does that randomly, but anyway according to the question the problem is having more yellow patches, limiting them does not help. I should have added that in my answer itself.

Comment: for limiting yellow patches, it would be more accurate to add another checkpoint to see what is the total number of yellow patches , and then the last patch which is allowed to recolor nearby patches will have some limit on how many patches it can turn yellow.

Comment: Hi @Marzy, thank you a lot for your help and for code simplification. Indeed, the principal is to have yellow patches arranged in Grid. I wanted to create grid from Green ones just to "localize" the center of my yellow patch and then create the yellow "splotch" around. It is true that I have to use if condition for "RateOfYellowPatches". Please, how can I create patchy surface but from yellow patches (clump of patches of the same color localized in Grid over world). Thank you again, I really appreciate it and I learned a lot !

Comment: just convert your green ones to yellow, or recolor nearby patches at the same time you create the center patches. in the second case you have no green patches at all.